# Restructure Array to Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array

i have a question to build up an associative arrays from a normal array (list).

**i have this:**

```
    $array = [
           't1/t1sub', 
           't1/t2sub', 
           't2/t1sub', 
           't3/t1sub', 
           't1/t4sub', 
           't4', 
           't1/t2sub/t1subsub', 
           't1/t2sub/t2subsub'
    ];
```

**and now i want this:**

```
    $target = [
        "t1" => [
            "t1sub",
            "t2sub" => [
                    "t1subsub",
                    "t2subsub"
            ],             
            "t4sub",
        ],
        "t2" => [
            "t1sub",
        ],
        "t3" => [
            "t1sub",
        ],
        "t4"
    ]
```

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the loop you already started.

```
$target = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('/', $item);

    if (!isset($target[$key])) {
        $target[$key] = [$value];
    } else {
        $target[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($target);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution - it is great but i forgot a feature ... i have edit the question. ... i needed an endless nesting of association (eg. `t1/t1sub/t1subsub/t1subsubsub` and so on ..)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to cut the elements in half and push the second half into subarrays that are keyed by the first half.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3l6Zh))

```
$array = ['t1/t1sub', 't1/t2sub', 't2/t1sub', 't3/t1sub', 't1/t4sub'];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $x = explode("/", $v);
    $result[$x[0]][] = $x[1];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  't1' => 
  array (
    0 => 't1sub',
    1 => 't2sub',
    2 => 't4sub',
  ),
  't2' => 
  array (
    0 => 't1sub',
  ),
  't3' => 
  array (
    0 => 't1sub',
  ),
)
```